# Exclude exposed ACF endpoint from WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wp-api

I'm using below snippet to expose my Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to the WP REST API. This pulls approximately 700 fields into the API, when I really just need one (acf.product_description_rows.product_row_type)

Is it a way to filter the ACF Fields and only include one?

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'bsd_register_acf_with_api' );
function bsd_register_acf_with_api() {
 if (!function_exists('get_fields')) return;

 register_rest_field(
 'product',
 'acf',
  array(
  'get_callback' => 'bsd_add_acf_fields',
  )
 );
}

function bsd_add_acf_fields( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
 $acf = get_fields( $object['id'] );
 return $acf;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - ACF now has support for the WP REST API

Hey all, Iain the Product Manager for Advanced Custom Fields here

As part of the [ACF 5.11](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/acf-5-11-release-rest-api/) release we added native support for ACF fields in the WordPress REST API. Read more about that [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/rest-api/).

This also allows you to filter which fields to expose the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Changing function `bsd_add_acf_fields()` like this should do it:

```
function bsd_add_acf_fields( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
  $acf = get_field( 'product_row_type', $object['id'] );
  return $acf;
}
```

Btw you can use the plugin [ACF to REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/) instead.

Comment: Thank you - I will test this out. I tried the plugin, and while it worked I couldnt figure out how to include specific fields only.